# Root of the trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to prove that following trigonometrical function does not have roots for $x$ in the range $(1,n/2)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$f(x)=\left[\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{x}\right)\right]^2+[\sin(x\pi)]^2$$

Another question is:

If there are no roots for the function $f(x)$ in range $x$ $(1,n/2)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, can we assert that the number $n$ is a prime?

Thank you,
Milovan Banicevic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sum of two squares is zero if and only if they are both zeros. So, you need both arguments to be a (integer) multiple of $\pi$.

The second $sin(x\pi)$ equals to zero trivialy for any integer $x$, so x has to be integer, otherwise the second term is not zero.

The first one requires that x must divide $n$ without a remainder (we already know x has to be an integer), otherwise we won't get an integer multiple of $\pi$. So, if there are no roots in the range from $1$ (but $1$ not including, since the interval is open) to $\frac n 2$, then there are no divisors of $n$, so there cannot possibly be any number dividing $n$, so $n$ is a prime number.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Can we confidently assert:
If there are roots for any value of n where x in the range (1,n/2) and where n∈N, than all value of roots are prime factors of n?

Thanks,
Milovan

Comment: Additional question:

Comment: If we apply Newton method to find roots of the function, do we have the prove that n is Prime (in the case there are no roots) or can we find all prime factors in the case when roots exists, for any value of n where x in the range (1,n/2) and where n∈N.

Comment: From the answer it is also obvious, that if n is composite number, then the function equals to zero if and only if x | n . But I am not sure, how effective the Newton method will be, or any method for finding roots of the function, because the values will get very close to zero and approximation would be required for such arguments, be it analytic or algorithmic approach in evaluating process, which will IMHO lead to imprecise results in the end.

Comment: Good analysis. Thanks